# Copy All Items within a Drive and Export to New Destination

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to copy all items within a drive and move them to a new destination using Powershell. At present, I've tried doing this with Copy-Item but am unable to do so within a drive. I've looked for solutions elsewhere but have yet to find a working fix, Any suggestions?

```
Copy-Item -Path 'P:' -Destination 'Destination'
```

Comment: I suggest robocopy. It's built for this kind of task.

Comment: Wouldn't `robocopy` be a good choice for a copy job? It's been made for.  ;-)

Comment: robocopy seems like the best way to go about it, i was able to copy items from my drive but cannot move it into the onedrive folder due to the spaces in the directory name. I think the best way would be to copy the items into a new folder with robocopy, then export that folder into the correct destination with Copy-Item. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: If you have spaces in the folder name you have to enclose the name in quotes. As you can see in the documentation for [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) it has an option `/mov`. I think that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying just to copy all of the items from one drive to a folder on another drive, you can use `Copy-Item`, like you are, with a few adjustments (`-Destination` path is just an example):

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\* -Destination F:\destinationPath -Recurse
```

Using the `*` in `C:\*` for the path tells the shell to get all files and directories at that folder, in this case, the `C:` root. `-Recurse` tells it to copy all files and directories recursively. Consider adding the `-Force` parameter if you want to use this in automation, as it will forcibly overwrite any existing files at the destination rather than prompt for input.